# Is there a log showing why a Windows server did not restart SQL Server after a reboot?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2

Our server was rebooted after a Windows Update scheduled for 1am, but after the restart SQL Server did not start up, so our websites were unable to display. Usually this process happens with no manual intervention.

Is there a log somewhere which might indicate the reason why the Windows startup process did not call SQL Server to get going again?

I've looked in the Event Viewer (Application Log) and SQL's own file E:\MSSQL\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG* but these only contain records of successful startup operations....nothing mentions a failed attempt to start a service or anything like that.

Comment: SQL should have its own section in the event viewer.  Did you also check the system log section? Service-related errors tend to appear here.

Comment: All the SQL events I found were in the Application log. None in System. I cannot see  a separate section for SQL, though I can see a Microsoft > Windows > blahblah section for 100 other programs.

Comment: You should be looking for errors thrown at startup by the `Service Control Manager` in the `System` log. Also, consider using [service recovery actions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753662.aspx) to just restart the service upon startup failure  - a number of service startup problems is transient (e.g. dependencies) and will go away a short while later.

Comment: Thank you, that was very clear. I have now found "A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service to connect." and a "failed to start" shortly after. It doesn't fully explain why, but at least it gives me a clue. Thanks.